# redirecting java output to two files

Tags: java, io

We are using Eclipe, Selenium, testng and java.  There is lots of code with
System.out.println() statements (several hundred or maybe even a few thousand).  All this output goes to the console (someone else left us with this).  We really want to get the output into a log file.

I did this (value of outputLogFile is set somewhere by the time it is used)

```
    java.io.PrintStream myout = null;
    ...
    myout = new java.io.PrintStream( new java.io.FileOutputStream( outputLogFile));
    System.out.println( "*** Logs will go to " + outputLogFile);
    System.setOut(myout);;
```

(There are appropriate try/catches, etc.  I just did not list everything.

This works.  Problem: output no longer goes to console.

Is there a way to split the output into two from System.out.println() so it goes BOTH to a console AND to a logfile?

Alternately, at the end of the test is there a way to copy everything from the console to a logfile?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extending `PrintStream` that saves the original System.out, then you can write there as well as to a file.

```
MyPrintStream newOut = MyPrintStream(System.out, "somefile.log");
System.setOut(newOut);
```

Comment: Does that require adding code at every single System.out.println() statement?  Or could you give me an example?  Thanks

Comment: I gave you the example, you just need to implement `MyPrintStream`.

Comment: Sorry.  I was in the middle of editing and missed the example.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking your test?  If you're running a command from a console, you could just redirect the output from the command line instead of changing the code.  For example, the 'tee' command in Linux does exactly what you want:

```
./my_test_script | tee logfile.txt
```

This would print the output of 'my_test_script' to the console as well as to logfile.txt.